# Suma de tiempos en SQL

Tags: sql, time

Tengo un problema, en el cual hago un `select` en `SQL` y quisiera sumar los tiempos de diferencia entre el tiempo inicial y el tiempo final, pero esto que no sea por incidente, si no en cuestión de tiempo

```
ID_Evento   Start_Time               End_Time                   min
23566       2019-11-14 08:37:38.567  2019-11-14 09:46:31.703    69
23567       2019-11-14 08:47:31.713  2019-11-14 11:22:45.833    155
```

En el ejemplo una sumarización de minutos seria 224, pero a tiempo que afecta al día serian 165 minutos ya que el primer evento inicio antes y termino pero el segundo evento que había sido abierto en el lapso del primero, termino después.

Espero haberme explicado y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Con código no se cómo hacerlo, pero tendrías que buscar el min(Start_Time) y el max(End_Time), tendrías qué ver si lo quieres diario, o cómo sería el filtro. Una vez tengas el tiempo inicial y el final, al final le restas el inicial y ya tienes el resultado que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí dejo una consulta que puede funcionar, aunque no es muy óptima y puede volverse lenta con muchas filas o grandes periodos. Lo que hace es contar los minutos que se encuentran en algún periodo.

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo(
    ID_Evento   int,
    Start_Time  datetime,
    End_Time    datetime);
INSERT INTO #Ejemplo
VALUES
        (23566, '20191114 08:37:38.567', '20191114 09:46:31.703'),
        (23567, '20191114 08:47:31.713', '20191114 11:22:45.833');


WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( --10,000 x 10,000 = 100,000,000 filas
    SELECT TOP((SELECT DATEDIFF( MI, MIN(Start_Time), MAX(End_Time))  FROM #Ejemplo)+ 1)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4 a, E4 b
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cteTally
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT *
              FROM #Ejemplo e
              WHERE DATEADD( MI, n, CAST( (SELECT MIN(Start_Time) FROM #Ejemplo) AS smalldatetime)) BETWEEN CAST( Start_Time AS smalldatetime) AND End_Time);
GO
```

Comment: Las 2 pruebas que he realizado han salido bien, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No es una consulta muy compleja, tomamos la hora de inicio mínima y la hora de finalización máxima y calculamos la diferencia en minutos:

```
select min(Start_time) as Start_time_Min, MAX(End_time) as End_time_Max, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(Start_time), MAX(End_time)) as Minutos
from Tabla;
```

El resultado:

```
Start_time_Min            End_time_Max                 Minutos
2019-11-14 08:37:38.567   2019-11-14 11:22:45.833      165
```

Comment: Pero no contemplas que puede haber tiempos en los que no haya algún incidente.